# VB.net how to pass the following to cmd

Tags: vb.net, cmd

Can someone help me please to write it correctly in Vb.net.

.bat file looks like this:

> CD "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\AzCopy"
>
> AzCopy /Source:https://projects.table.core.windows.net/table/ /Dest:C:Users\user\Downloads\ /SourceKey:key

I can use Process.Run and just run the bat file but I need more flexibility with user names, paths and access keys that are in the string.

Comment: Study the Process type more closely,  You can specify arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass arguments to process calls, yours would look something like this:

```
Dim p As New System.Diagnostics.Process
p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\AzCopy"
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/Source:https://projects.table.core.windows.net/table/ /Dest:C:Users\user\Downloads\ /SourceKey:key"
p.Start()
```

Just build the arguments string with whatever parameters you need to pass to the file

Comment: Ok. There is smth going wrong. I added azcope.exe to the end for the fileName. the window closes so fast I can`t even read the output or error message. Any ideas how to keep window open?